# How to keep my React code from being minified on Github?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, create-react-app, github-pages

I'm fairly new on the React scene and just finished a few small react applications. I deployed two of these applications to Github Pages, and they both function perfectly.
However, I noticed that the files in my repository  are **minified**. Not only that, but the language meter shows it as 100% html. It's nitpicky, but I'd like for it to display JavaScript/CSS too. I would greatly prefer my files be visible, just in case anyone wanted to look at how my application was built (mainly recruiters).

- Is there some way to make these files visible/**UN**minified without sacrificing performance?
- Is there any reason I wouldn't necessarily need to undertake this? --> *(would employers care?)*

Comment: You're committing your built project, but you should upload the source code!

Comment: @Federico awsome! That must be why people's react project has a main branch with the source code and a gh-pages with 'built' code.. That's exactly what I need, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're committing your built project, but you should upload the source code!

To expose your github pages you have to build the project inside the `docs` folder, so you can have source code and build on the same branch!